# Popup flex window

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

When I click the button, it should popup my module, when i click outside it will hide or remove it. This is the code I have:

```
private var Showup:IFlexDisplayObject; 
Showup = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, samplemodule, false);
Showup.addEventListener(FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE, Removewindow); 

private function Removewindow(e:FlexMouseEvent):void
{
    PopUpManager.removePopUp(Showup);
}
```

My problem is, in `samplemodule` I have lot of buttons. When I click any button the corresponding module should load to middle portion.. but it does not load.

Please tell me the mistake or an alternative option!

Comment: I've reworded your question a bit, could you double check I've not accidently altered the meaning?

Answer (score 2):

Please add

```
mouseDownOutside="PopUpManager.removePopUp(this)"
```

tag inside you samplemodule (Popping canvas)  main Display object as tag.

This will remove the popup when you are moving outside the popup and clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are having trouble with, the close or the centering of the popup.  I think it is the centering.  If so, try adding:

```
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(Showup);
```